# Why does RPM increase when you lean the mixture in constant speed propeller engine?

Tags: general-aviation, piston-engine, constant-speed-propeller, diamond-da40

In constant speed propeller aircraft like Diamond star DA-40, during run-up checks the AFM mentioned to increase throttle to increase RPM to 2000 and then do magneto check then rpm check then mixture check which to lean it and watch for RPM increase EGT and CHT increase .. although RPM increase by 20 to 50 RPM .. i am curious to know why

Comment: This isn't unique to constant speed props - it's a function of reciprocating engines, including those in cars etc.  See this answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73066/why-does-pulling-the-mixture-to-idle-cutoff-increase-the-rpm-slightly

Comment: Sorry, fat-fingered the review... meant to mark close as dupe. My vote shows "leave open", that's not what I intended.

Answer (score 4):

It's because at the power setting you are using for those checks, the prop is still "off the governor"; the blades are still at their fine pitch stops, because the governor is calling for max RPM, say 2700 (you have the prop control full forward), and you only have enough throttle for 2000 even with the blades at full fine pitch.

So in effect, your propeller is still a "fixed" pitch propeller (sitting against the fine pitch stops trying to let the engine wind up to the governor setting, but there isn't enough torque present to get above 2000) and so RPM is sensitive to torque changes like with a regular fixed pitch prop.

When you add throttle for take off, RPM will increase as the blades stay on the fine pitch stops until you get to 2700 (or whatever the setting is), then stop rising above 2700 as you continue to add throttle.  At the point where RPM stops rising, you are "on the governor" and the blades are coming off the stops to regulate the load on the engine to keep the RPM at 2700.

Comment: I think OP wants to know why leaning at a constant throttle position results in a few RPMs increase.

Comment: I thought the question was about why there is an RPM increase at all (mixture, mags, whatever) when it's a CS prop. We need the OP to clarify.